# Android How to add intervals texts in a seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using a seekbar, and I want to add certain marks in the seekbar with text to use it as a scale. The selected interval points should be highlighted.
[image]

The corresponding code is here:

```
   seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekbar.setMax(max);
    seekbar.setProgress(50);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            value.setText("SeekBar value is " + progress);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: How did you finally solve it /?

Answer (score 6):

To make the above seek bar you first have to add a measuring scale as a background drawable. Then you'll have to make textboxes for each interval on the measuring scale.

```
<SeekBar 
        ....
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        ....
/>
```

Then

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {   
   progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/interval))*interval;
   seekBar.setProgress(progress);
   if(progress==5) textBox5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   else if(progress==10) textBox10.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   //......... for all the text boxes.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, all The above solutions force to select the last progress point, which is not logic.

To make it mire accurete, Seek bar must detect which is the nearest dot and jump to it.

So below is the solution,

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    int progressStep = getMax() / dotsCount;

    int lastDotProgress = Math.round(getProgress() / progressStep) * progressStep;
    int nextDotProgress = lastDotProgress + progressStep;
    int midBetweenDots = lastDotProgress + (progressStep / 2);

    if (getProgress() > midBetweenDots)
        seekBar.setProgress(nextDotProgress);
    else
        seekBar.setProgress(lastDotProgress);
}
```

You can use same behavior in onProgressChanged() if you want to prevent seeking between dots

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {   
 int s_size=5;
    progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/s_size))*s_size;
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
    textview.setText(progress + "");
}
```

> what you want to settext get easily get from progress and
>   textview.settext() value

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want a measuring scale type of seekbar

Comment: String check=(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()); if(check..equalsIgnoreCase("somthing what you want compare")){//code above textview.settext(); or setcolor}